# How to rescue my work if Google Docs crashes

Tags: google-docs

Google Docs didn't save some changes and crashed with the message
`Unable to load file. Try to load it again or send an error report. [Reload]`

I see the text I wrote in the background, but I can't select it to copy&paste it, it's grayed out. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't help. How can I rescue the text I wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Google Chrome:

- Right click, Inspect
- Hover over a tag (for example `<html>`) such that the Google Docs editor is highlighted
- Right click, Copy, Copy outerHTML
- Paste somewhere
- Optionally, remove HTML tags, for example with a regex like `s/<(.*?)>//`
- Optionally, if you want to detect differences with the version that Google Docs saved, use [FineDiff](http://www.raymondhill.net/finediff/viewdiff-ex.php) or so